# Refresh webbrowser content

Tags: c#, jquery, webbrowser-control

I have windows forms application with WebBrowser control. And I have DocumentCompleted event handler which modifies document inner html:

```
public void DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var browser = (sender as WebBrowser);
    if (browser != null && browser.Document != null && browser.Document.Body != null)
    {
        var documentHtml = browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
        browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml = Replacer.Replace(documentHtml);
    }
}
```

And I have another method:

```
public void Inject(string element, string contents)
{
    var browser = webBrowser;
    if (browser != null && browser.Document != null && browser.Document.Body != null)
    {
        HtmlElement htmlElement = browser.Document.GetElementById(element);
        if (htmlElement != null)
        {
            htmlElement.InnerHtml = contents;
        }
    }
}
```

This method I use to inject html page (variable "contents") inside existing page. It's something like jquery "load": `$("#divisionId").load("path_to_html_page");`
In injected html page there is some javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // some code here
    });
</script>
```

When executing `htmlElement.InnerHtml = contents;` only html markup is loaded but document ready function isn't executed. How can I call this function manually or make WebBrowser refresh it's modified content to execute this function?